# Problem with XAMPP after installation

Tags: macos, osx-server, apache, webserver

I have just installed XAMPP and when I click "start all" nothing actually starts since there is a problem with the some configurations (I do not have any idea of what those lines mean since I am a completely novice in servers). I just to have everything running in order to be able to start my PHP course.
Here goes what is written in the application log (upper tab):

```
Starting all servers...
Starting MySQL Database...

Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
Starting ProFTPD...
Exit code: 8
Stdout:
Checking syntax of configuration file
proftpd config test fails, aborting
Stderr:
MacBook-Pro-de-Gloria.local proftpd[47065]: warning: unable to determine IP address of 'MacBook-Pro-de-Gloria.local'
MacBook-Pro-de-Gloria.local proftpd[47065]: error: no valid servers configured
MacBook-Pro-de-Gloria.local proftpd[47065]: Fatal: error processing configuration file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf'
```

I do not know if this info could be useful but my OS version is Sierra 10.12.6

Please feel free to ask me more details in the case you need additional information to find out what the problem is

Thanks in advance! :)

Edit: Here is what the file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf has

```
# This is a basic ProFTPD configuration file (rename it to 
# 'proftpd.conf' for actual use.  It establishes a single server
# and a single anonymous login.  It assumes that you have a user/group
# "daemon" and "ftp" for normal operation and anon.

ServerName          "ProFTPD"
ServerType          standalone
DefaultServer           on

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                21
# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new dirs and files
# from being group and world writable.
Umask               022

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd)
MaxInstances            30

# Set the user and group that the server normally runs at.
User daemon
Group      admin

# Normally, we want files to be overwriteable.
<Directory /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/*>
  AllowOverwrite        on
</Directory>

# only for the web servers content
DefaultRoot /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs

<Limit SITE_CHMOD>                                                                                                                                                         
  DenyAll                                                                                                                                                                  
</Limit>  

# daemon gets the password "xampp"
UserPassword daemon 2TgxE8g184G9c

# daemon is no normal user so we have to allow users with no real shell
RequireValidShell off

# daemon may be in /etc/ftpusers so we also have to ignore this file
#to login with "OSX Users"
AuthPAM on
AuthPAMConfig ftpd
UseFtpUsers off
```

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what's wrong - `proftpd config test fails`.  This means you have an issue with that particular config file.  Without seeing it, we have no idea how to fix.

Comment: Hello Alan, I'll add that information to my question then. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Do you already have Apache running on your system?  Try `sudo apachectl stop` then try again.

Comment: Hello again. After copying that in the terminal I got this: /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist: Could not find specified service

Comment: Which version of XAMPP did you install exactly? 7.2.1 or 7.2.1vm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is found here:
https://serverfault.com/questions/617591/proftpd-unable-to-determine-ip-address/617593#617593

you will need to do an `ifconfig` at the command line and post it. We will also need you to provide your hostname by posting the output of `cat /etc/hosts`.

Then you will change `/etc/hosts` to

```
x.x.x.x  MacBook-Pro-de-Gloria.local
xxxx:xxxx:xxx:xx::x MacBook-Pro-de-Gloria.local
```

The IP addresses above will be provided by ifconfig (assuming this server is on your own system). It is likely that the IP address will be 127.0.0.1, and the IPv6 address will start with fe80:

or (better) fix the setup to have a proper [FQDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) and naming scheme.